# Regular Expression not containing

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression that matches the following conditions:

```
logger(textthatdoesnotcontain|)
```

Example:

```
logger(sample log) // Match
logger(sample log | test) // Not Match
```

I have tried below regex, but not working:

```
logger(?!*\|.*)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`logger\([^\|]+\)` should do the trick

Or if you want to match whole lines

```
^logger\([^\|]+\)$
```

This accept any character except "|" between "logger(" and ")"

Answer (score 2):

If you want your line to not match if it contains `|`, you can just use this regex,

```
^logger\([^|]*$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h6cvOl/1)**

You don't need a negative look ahead when you want to fail the match just because of one character and can use negated character set for such use cases like this `[^|]`